# I m trying to mock the .header but it does not work, does anyone has an idea?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-webflux, webclient

i tried to mock the header with  when(requestHeadersSpec.header(notNull(), notNull())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);, or something similar but i does not work, does anyone has an idea?

```
  return defaultWebClient
            .get()
            .uri(some uri)
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf"))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
```

.....
}

this is how i tried to write the unit test
when(defaultWebClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
doReturn(requestHeadersSpec).when(requestHeadersUriSpec).uri(anyString());
Mockito.when(requestHeadersSpec.header(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
DefaultDataBufferFactory factory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();

```
    DefaultDataBuffer dataBuffer =
        factory.wrap(ByteBuffer.wrap("{\"username\":\"foo\",\"password\":\"bar\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    when(responseSpec.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class))
        .thenReturn(Flux.just(dataBuffer));
```

Comment: Please include more details, the source for the test where you're trying to mock out the headers would help.

Comment: i added the unit test mocks

Comment: Please read through this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as there still aren't enough details in your question to properly answer it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like below

```
.withHeader(
  HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, 
  containing(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
)
```